# Window (no GUI) is cut off and doesn't show everything

Tags: arraylist, window

Screenshot:

[image]

I am printing this array list. Above it is supposed to be the menu, however everything is cut and I can only see the bottom records from the array list (when the array list is larger than my monitor AND a little bit more). There is a scroll bar on the right but it doesn't scroll high enough for me to see all the records and the console menu. No GUI is used and the window is not a JFrame. When the array list has only a couple of records everything works perfectly fine so there isn't some kind of clear screen. Do I have to make a JFrame to solve this problem? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the buffer size of the terminal window. You can raise the value and it will display more lines.

Comment: How do I do that? Sorry I'm very bad with java and bluej

Comment: Check the options of the terminal window for something like "scrollback buffer size".